# Como excluir um elemento usando a biblioteca list do C++?

Tags: c++, lista

Olá, fiz minhas buscas na internet e não cheguei a solução que preciso, estou com um programa que cria um grafo (direcionado ou não), em que o usuário pode excluir um de seus vértices ou um vizinho específicos do vértice.

Estou usando a biblioteca list do C++ para criar a estrutura do meu grafo, meu grafo possui um ponteiro para minha lista chamado *adj, para acessar um vértice uso adj[i]. Porém no meu código, a função remove() está retornando erro de null pointer.

Segue trechos do código:

```c
// CLASSE GRAFO

class Grafo {

    list<int>* adj; // Lista de Adjacência

    // DECLARA METODOS
    void removeVertice(int v);

    void removeVizinho(int v, int vizinho);

};


// Remove Vertice
void Grafo::removeVertice(int v) {
    
    // Aqui Gera Erro
    adj->remove(v);
    
}

// Remove Vizinho
void Grafo::removeVizinho(int v, int vizinho) {

    // Percorre vizinhos de V
    for (auto i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); i++) {
        if (*i == vizinho) {

            // Aqui Gera Erro
            adj[v].remove(*i);

        }
    }

}

int main () {

    Grafo grafo(3);

    grafo.addVertice(0, 1);
    grafo.addVertice(0, 2);

    grafo.addVertice(1, 0);
    grafo.addVertice(1, 2);

    grafo.addVertice(2, 0);
    grafo.addVertice(2, 1);


    grafo.removeVizinho(0 , 1);

    grafo.removeVertice(0);

}
```

A pergunta é: Estou usando as funções certas? Ou será que o erro está na forma como estou referenciando as posições??

Comment: A função remove() aceita o valor do elemento. Se quiseres apagar pelo índice tens de usar a função erase().